# Magento - doesn't send any email

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento

i have a problem with mail sending: magento doesn't send any mail, i'm trying to use the sendfriend functionality (i've extendend the ProductController of that Sendfriend module), but the problem is about any email (i've tried to do a registration or to change a password, but no email was sent). backend settings seems to be ok:

```
System->Configuration->system->Mail sending settings->disable Email Communications->No;

System->Configuration->system->Mail sending settings->Host ->locahost;
```

with the same settings on another local magento installation the system send emails correctly. what can i check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to do any coding stuff. Its already available in Magento. You just need to enable the option of **Email to a friend** from the back-end. Hope this help you.

Comment: No, was not that. I had no mail transport agent configured locally. Solved through this workaround applied to core (not committed): http://www.betasix.net/using-external-smtp-server-gmail-in-magento/. Quick and easy rather than configuring sendmail or other